# Three.JS, any idea to create sliding for Three.js?

Tags: slider, three.js, webgl

I am thinking to develop some tools for my prototype system. I saw a function in the following link and seems very useful for me as well. But I dont know how to implement it? any idea?

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9c0e319bfaff4d33a0fe2da97c2c3fd7

Thanks!!!

[image: sliding tool]

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Currently I have a colladaloader to render a building. But I would like to have a tool like the above-mentioned tool. This tool can hide walls on the right window and keep them on the left. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but you could create two viewports, both rendering the scene from the same camera, but before you render the viewport for the right-side half, set the `visible` flag of walls (and other Mesh objects as necessary) to `false`, and after rendering the right-side scene reset those flags to `true`.   This wouldn't implement the slider, however.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Is it possible to have two viewports in a scene with the ability to represent a building differently. As you said the left viewport render walls and the right one doesnt render walls? http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html